# reading piped stdin and user input

Tags: c++, file-io, stdin

I'm writing a program for a c++ data structures class that reads in a space separated file and I wrote a small function so that I could pipe in different files and work with them, but I would also like to take user input using cin and it seems that the buffer is just looping.  I'm sort of beyond my depth here, but here's my input function.  I'm running the program by $ cat filename | ./compiledexec.  I was hoping someone might know why using cin in other places doesn't wait for user input and perhaps help with a solution?

```
    void catchPipe(int dataArray[][9]);
    int main(){
        int inArray[9][9];
        int column;
        catchPipe(inArray);

        cout << "Which column would you like to check?";
        cin >> column;  // This input is skipped totally.
        functionChecksIfInCol(column);  //Function  called with garbage value
        cout << "end program" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    void catchPipe(int dataArray[][9]){
        int i;
        int n=0;
        int pos=0;
        string mystring;
        while(cin){
            getline(cin, mystring);
            if( n < 9 ){
                for(i = 0; i < mystring.length(); i++){
                    if( (int)mystring[i] != 32 ){
                        dataArray[n][pos] = mystring[i] - '0';
                        pos++;
                    }   
                }pos =0; 
            ++n;
            }   
        }   
    }// end catchPipe()
     //Sample File input:     
    0 8 0 1 7 0 0 0 3   
    0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 9   
    0 9 0 0 3 0 5 4 8   
    0 0 4 0 9 0 0 0 0   
    0 0 0 7 0 3 0 0 0   
    0 0 0 0 1 0 4 0 0   
    6 1 9 0 8 0 0 5 0   
    7 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 0   
    2 0 0 0 6 4 0 1 0
```

Thanks!

The program fills in my inArray, but it skips the next call to cin.  I'm assuming this is because stdin has been redirected from the keyboard to the pipe from linux?  Maybe I can declare another istream object and direct it to the keyboard or something?  I'm not sure what to do here

Answer (score 0):

Use a vector:

```
void cachePipe(std::vector<std::vector<int>> data)
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        std::vector<int> fill((std::istream_iterator<int>(line)),
                            std::istream_iterator<int>());
        data.push_back(fill);
    }
}
```

Comment: How will this allow me to reuse cin for keyboard input in the program?  The problem I'm having is that any later calls of cin are being skipped instead of asking the user for input.

Comment: @Matt Can you show me an example of this behavior `cin` is giving you? It could just be that one of the stream state flags are on. Try doing `cin.clear()` before any subsequent input operations.

Comment: I did try a cin.clear().  I cant really give an example, but its basically skipping my other cin calls.  I'll put some more code in my post to give you an idea of what the program does.  I'm basically filling a two dimensional int array with the string input from the linux pipe.

Comment: I have the same problem with the input buffer being flushed by cin.ignore(1000,'\n') and cin flag state reset (cin.clear()). The program works interactively just fine but if I try to pipe the input to it, it just goes to an infinite loop upon having something nasty piped as if all those remedy operations on input buffer are ignored.

Comment: @EsmuIgors When you pipe input to the program, it's recieved as an argument to the program. Program arguments can be accessed through the parameters of your `int main()` function. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/

Comment: @0x499602D2, I get Your point but it won't do. The program is _supposed_ to be interactive, I just don't want  to enter all the stuff every time I check new features.

Comment: If you pipe data to the program that's how it needs to be parsed. Your other option is to put everything into a file and use `fstream`. I'm not aware of any other way.

Comment: Well, with getline() piping works and eveything happens just like if I interactively put that data in. With bare cin it just doesn't.